# How can I trim string property datatypes from database char datatypes in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I have a SQL database and a Oracle database with the same schema.

Therefore I want to use my model classes for the two databases and all I will do is change the database connection string in the Fluent NHibernate configuration.

I have some database char data types for columns but in my model classes I have set them as string however when they are returned from queries they have padded white space.

How do I return them trimmed without causing problems when I query the database using these colums as they will need to match the fixed length specification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an implementation of `NHibernate.UserTypes.IUserType` that will trim the whitespace when fetched from the database and re-pad it when going back to the database.

In your fluent mapping, you just add `.CustomType<T>` where `T` is your `IUserType` implementation.

[This article](http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx) is helpful for properly implementing `IUserType`. Don't get hung up on methods like `Assemble`, `Disassemble`, `DeepCopy`, `Replace` -- it doesn't look like you'll ever hit those, even. You're most concerned with `NullSafeGet`, in which you'll trim, and `NullSafeSet` in which you'll re-pad.

#### update

Upon further consideration, I'm not sure you'll actually need to re-pad the value when inserting to the database -- the db itself will enforce the fixed length of the column.

In response to the link you provided in your comment, I think that implementation pretty much gets you there, but I do think you might need to modify it a bit. For one thing, you may not want to trim both leading and trailing whitespace, as `Trim()` will do. For another, in your override of `Equals`, you'll want

> ```
>      value
> ```

to equal

> value

Comment: I've found this. Do you think it will work? http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#5DDdVc0kQuk/trunk/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns/UserTypes/TrimString.cs&q=trimstring%20package:http://unhaddins%5C.googlecode%5C.com

Comment: How is your suggestion of Equals different than that in the link?

Comment: @Jon Sorry, my whitespace was being lost by the markdown parsing. I just mean you want "value" to be considered equal even if it is padded to the column length.

Comment: Within the database, the dbms will enforce the fact that 'value   ' and '  value ' are not equal. Whether it's safe for application code to assume that those two are equal anyway is application-specific. (Meaning it will be hard or impossible for anyone here to give you very much help answering that question.) I'd be really cautious here if I were you--talk to your DBA.

Comment: The link I posted and have tested on trims when it returns from the database and when it sets it to the database.  Doing a search where person name = "John" and not "John     " does seem to work ie/it returns the data

Answer (score 3):

The char data type in SQL databases is padded with whitespace.

If you can modify the database, you can create a view that trims the columns. But a trimmed value won't match the untrimmed value. (In a SQL query, that is.) TRIM() is a standard SQL function, but not all platforms support it. I suppose you might be able to cast it to VARCHAR(); I'm not sure I've ever tried that.

If I were in your shoes, I think I'd cache literally the value the database contains. (That is, I'd store it in a variable of some kind.) I might trim it for display to the user, but any interaction between my application code and the database would be done using the actual values in the database.

Comment: I've found this. Do you think it will work? http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#5DDdVc0kQuk/trunk/uNhAddIns/uNhAddIns/UserTypes/TrimString.cs&q=trimstring%20package:http://unhaddins%5C.googlecode%5C.com

Comment: Maybe. See Jon's comments above, along with my caveat.

Comment: @Catcall Thank you. Resolved my issue before I even had to ask!